# in VB.net, if nth digit after decimal is Zero, then Round function will apply for 7 digit

Tags: vb.net, math, rounding

let say `n decimal = 0.996010569`

I have applied below code (round on 6th digit) :

```
txtDiscountRate.Text = Math.Round(Val(txtDiscountRate.Text.Trim), 6)
```

But since here its 6th digit is 0 (Zero), so its value become 0.99601.
But i wish it would be 0.996011.

logic is: if 6th digit is 0 or < 5 then it do Round from 7th digit
then our calculation will be right.

Please provide Code in VB.net.

---

Jerry
in above code. 
CInt(Str(1).Char(5))  is   showing error this error  ----->   " 'Char' is not a member of 'String'".

Scenario is described below:

in txtDiscountRate.text  have value   "0.996010500406591"     .

in my coding i did
 txtDiscountRate.Text = Math.Round(Val(txtDiscountRate.Text.Trim), 6)  .    (means considering round till digit throught)

so it giving value   0.99601           which is because of 6th digit after decimal is 0,

but i want to put condition, in decimal value, if on 6th digit after decimal is ( 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 ) and 7th digit after decimal is available then it round till 7th position.

else  it round till 6th position.

Comment: It already produces 0.996011.  You need to provide a better example.  After taking a closer look at the Math.Round() overload that takes a MidpointRounding argument and thinking a bit about the wisdom of assigning a variable of type String with a Double.

Comment: It was supposed to be `Str(1).Chars(5)`, my bad. Besides, I'm Vincent, not Jerry. (:

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FormatNumber()` function.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the best and prettiest solution, but you can give it a try...

```
Dim Dec As Decimal = 0.996010569
Dim str() As String = Split(CStr(Dec), ".")

If CInt(Str(1).Chars(5)) < 5 Then 'It's Char number 5 since it's a zero-based index. So the first number = Index 0.
    txtDiscountRate.Text = Math.Round(Val(txtDiscountRate.Text.Trim), 7)
Else
    txtDiscountRate.Text = Math.Round(Val(txtDiscountRate.Text.Trim), 6)
End If
```